# Undefined reference

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I'm getting this linker error. I know a way around it, but it's bugging me because another part of the project's linking fine and it's designed almost identically.

First, I have namespace `LCD`. Then I have two separate files, LCDText.h and LCDGraphic.h.

LCDText.h:

```
//[snip]
void TextDraw(Widget *w);

void TextBarDraw(Widget *w);

void TextHistogramDraw(Widget *w);

void TextIconDraw(Widget *w);

void TextBignumsDraw(Widget *w);

void TextGifDraw(Widget *w);

}; // End namespace
```

LCDGraphic.h:

```
//[snip]
void GraphicDraw(Widget *w);

void GraphicIconDraw(Widget *w);

void GraphicBarDraw(Widget *w);

void GraphicHistogramDraw(Widget *w);

void GraphicBignumsDraw(Widget *w);

void GraphicGifDraw(Widget *w);

}; // End namespace
```

And in WidgetBignums.h I have:

```
//[snip]
using namespace LCD;

extern void TextBignumsDraw(Widget *w);
extern void GraphicBignumsDraw(Widget *w);

template <class T>
WidgetBignums<T>::WidgetBignums(Generic<T> *v, std::string n, Json::Value *section,
    int row, int col) : Widget(n, section, row, col,
    WIDGET_TYPE_BIGNUMS | WIDGET_TYPE_RC | WIDGET_TYPE_SPECIAL) {

    if( v->GetType() == LCD_TEXT )
        Draw = TextBignumsDraw; // Line 66
    else if( v->GetType() == LCD_GRAPHIC )
        Draw = GraphicBignumsDraw;
    else
        Draw = NULL;
//[snip]
```

And I get the following linker error:

```
LCDControl.o: In function `WidgetBignums':
/home/starlon/Projects/LCDControl/WidgetBignums.h:66: undefined reference to `LCD::TextBignumsDraw(LCD::Widget*)'
```

Now here's one way to fix it, but I don't like it. I can move `LCD::TextBignumsDraw` outside of the `LCD` namespace and it works. Strange enough, the linker sees `LCD::GraphicBignumsDraw`. Any clues?

Edit: I'm using gcc 4.4.1-2 on Fedora 11. Using SCons to compile.

Edit: Here's WidgetBignums, showing `Draw`.

```
template <class T>
class WidgetBignums : public Widget {
    Generic<T> *visitor_;
    std::vector<char> FB_;
    std::vector<char> ch_;
    int min_;
    int max_;
    int update_;
    int layer_;
    Property *expression_;
    Property *expr_min_;
    Property *expr_max_;

    QTimer *timer_;

    void (*Draw)(Widget *);

    public:
    WidgetBignums(Generic<T> *visitor, std::string name, Json::Value *section, int row, int col);
    ~WidgetBignums();
    void TextScroll() {};
    void SetupChars();
    void Update();
    void Start();
    void Stop();
    std::vector<char> GetFB() { return FB_; }
    std::vector<char> GetCh() { return ch_; }
    Generic<T> *GetVisitor() { return visitor_; }
};
```

Edit: Here's `TextBignumsDraw`'s signature.

```
//[snip]
void TextBignumsDraw(Widget *w) {
//[snip]
```

Edit: Incidentally, I'm getting the same error for `TextHistogramDraw` and `TextGifDraw` as well. `TextIconDraw` and the others are fine.

Comment: How are you linking in the library?  Which compiler/linker are you using?

Comment: can you post the code file that includes "WidgetBignums.h" .. maybe WidgetBignums.cpp ?

Comment: @Andrew: I included the class itself. Tell me if you need something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where is the definition for `LCD::TextBignumsDraw()`?  That's what the linker seems to be complaining about.  Not the declaration, but the actual definition of the function.

The fact that when you move the declaration out of namespace `LCD` things start working indicates that the definition for `TextBignumsDraw()` is in the global namespace, not the `LCD` namespace.

This (in some .cpp file):

```
void TextBignumsDraw(Widget *w) {
    // ...
}
```

Needs to be wrapped in a

```
namespace LCD {

}
```

block.

Comment: I added the namespace to the function's signature. Strange that the other functions work fine without it. Thanks for the nudge.

Answer (score 1):

Try dropping the "using namespace LCD", and change that line 66 to:

```
Draw = LCD::TextBignumsDraw;
```

That's more explicit, which may help the linker understand what you're asking for.

Besides, you should never say "using namespace Anything" in a header file.  It hoists everything in that namespace out into the global space for every user of that header.  That almost completely destroys the value of having a namespace in the first place.  You should hoist things out like this in the narrowest scope that's practical.  Sometimes I put "using namespace foo" at the top of a single function, for instance, if that's the only user of the bits in the namespace within a given `.cpp` file.